# How to force proj4 to build proj.dll instead of proj_4_9.dll including version using cmake

Tags: build, cmake, proj

How to force proj4 to build proj.dll instead of proj_4_9.dll including version using cmake?

I tried to

```
set(OUTPUT_NAME "proj" CACHE STRING "")
set(PROJ_CORE_TARGET "proj" CACHE STRING "")
set(PROJ_CORE_TARGET_OUTPUT_NAME "proj" CACHE STRING "")
```

to manually override this. However... did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the name of a target like so:

```
set_target_properties(proj_4_9 PROPERTIES 
  OUTPUT_NAME "proj")
```

Comment: Worked, thx. Assumed there is a variable to set globally like PROJ_OUTPUTNAME or so...